# viewDidLoad gets called, viewWillAppear does not get called, view does not appear on screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

**Update**

It has been mentioned that viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear do not get called per the docs.
However, I perform no initialization within these methods and no adding UI elements to the view.

I was just using them to place break points to try to debug this.

Any other ideas?

---

**Original Question**

I'm stumped. I'm refactoring some code and have come across some strange behavior....

I initialize viewController A without a nib and set the view programmatically.

viewDidLoad in controller A gets called.

Inside viewDidLoad of viewController A, I initialize viewController B from a nib.

I add viewControllerB.view as a subview of viewControllerA.view

viewDidload of controller B gets called.

---

Then it gets weird:

1. viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear of
   viewController B **never** get
   called.
2. viewControllerB.view **never** makes
   it on screen.
3. **No** errors.

---

Things I checked:

The name of the viewControllerBs Nib is correct.

The view outlet of viewControllerB is connected to a view.

viewControllerB and its view both are non-nil.

And to top it off, everything works great in SDK [redacted] beta 5!

Any ideas?
It's got to be something silly..

Comment: So this works on sdk3 but not on earlier ones?

Comment: See Ramin's answer about the viewWillAppear mystery.  It's in the docs, but its not easy to find.  Not sure why viewControllerB never makes it to the screen.  Are you doing any important initialization in viewWillApeear?

Comment: +1 for list of things checked before asking question here

Comment: No, I perform no initialization outside viewDidLoad(s)

And yes it works in 3.0, I'm continuing to do my normal coding by compiling for 3.0, but I really want to have this compile in 2.2.1 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the matter:

I could never find a solution, but since then SDK 3.0 is the standard and the point has become moot. The code does work correctly in current versions of the SDK.

Answer (score 22):

If the view controller is added to a view hierarchy through code, the view controller will not get `viewWillAppear` (or `viewDidAppear`) messages. If you add it yourself you have to send the view controller the message yourself.

Comment: thanks, that helps me understand why the viewWillAppears/didAppears aren't being called. However, the problem persists

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to call

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

Wherever you redefine it.

The documentation says:

> If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

Comment: I am using a storyboard with nav controllers/viewcontrollers and viewDidAppear wasn't being called... the reason was I had commented out [super viewDidAppear:animated] from my custom subclass that one of my viewControllers inherited from. Doh! No idea why I originally did that (I think to solve a race condition.) Uncommenting this out fixed the issue! Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
// whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your view is not the root view. You are probably using a UINavigationController so try to implement this method

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or this one

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and add in your viewDidLoad

```
this.navController.delegate = self;
```

(don't forget to add the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol in your .h file.