# ViewWillAppear on iPad

Tags: iphone, uiview, viewwillappear

my question is that i use ios 4.1 and viewWillAppear is not call when i go via

```
[self.view addSubView:self.mySecondView.view];
```

then and in the first view i alloc second view on `ViewDidLoad` .. i just want to call `ViewWillApear` on Second View because want to do the task dynamic.

is their some thing alternative... because `InitWithNibName` method also fire when alloc and init occur.. i want to fire some method when i add to that view.

Thanks

Comment: I think that you are confusing the purpose of the view and the view controller. Looks to me like mySecondView is a view controller and just instantiating a view controller and adding its view to another view does not work as expected (I partially blame UIWindow's original implementation of addSubview on this misconception). You may need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue is discussed before,Just go through below SO links.

[iPhone viewWillAppear not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing)

[viewDidLoad gets called, viewWillAppear does not get called, view does not appear on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895713/viewdidload-gets-called-viewwillappear-does-not-get-called-view-does-not-appear)

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=575530

here is the tutorial post

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/viewWillAppear.html